# How to set Webview timeout natively on Android?

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm struggling to find how to set **timeout** for the

> WebView

All suggestions wants me to use **Runnable/handlers** and other workarounds, which is not good.

**WebViewClient** has static field:

```
/** Connection timed out */
    public static final int ERROR_TIMEOUT = -8;
```

so there is should be some way to set it!

**Cordova** actually uses the same workaround, so I guess that there is no way of doing it via SDK. But maybe there is someone who knows how to set the thing.

[Cordova Source code](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/23fd0982b0faa6b7e169c2946eab07930f1f4d16/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewImpl.java#L145)

Comment: ERROR_TIMEOUT looks like the code for a message, the question is, who is using that value?

Comment: @lelloman, yeah sort of. I'm pretty sure that I've got the error code several times in onErrorRecieved method. I just want to adjust it. Actually the question is how to set specific timeout time when onErrorRecieved would be executed.

Comment: that value has nothing to do with the timeout time, it's just an error code, why would you like to change it?

Comment: @lelloman I mentioned the value just because it is used by android and was returned to me in one of error callbacks. The question is how to set webview timeout natively.